# Changing URLs for SEO purposes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, permalinks

I have a site that currently has URLS that look like this

```
http://localhost:3000/public/category/1?category_id=1
```

That the SEO guy has requested be changed to this

```
http://localhost:3000/(:category_name)-leasing
```

where (:category_name) is the name of the category referenced by `category_id=1` and is appended with "-leasing"

Is it possible to set this up without creating a new column in my category model for a permalink.

Currently I also have this in my routes.rb file:

```
get ':permalink', :to => 'public#show'
```

which displays items from the category mentioned above as

```
http://localhost:3000/item-name-from-permalink
```

Is this going to prevent a category using the same url structure? will rails be able to distinguish between a `:permalink` and a `(:category_name)-leasing` url or will the url need to something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/category/(:category_name)-leasing
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_param
    "#{self.id}-#{self.title.parameterize}"
  end

end
```

will produce url like `http://localhost:3000/categories/1-some-good-title`